# Does $\int_e^\infty{\frac{\ln(x)^\alpha}{x}dx}$ exists?

Tags: improper-integrals

My task is to determine wetherthe integral $\int_e^\infty{\frac{\ln(x)^\alpha}{x}\,dx}$ does exist or not in depencence of $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

For that I wrote $b$ instead of $\infty$ and then calculated the integral using substitution, which should be $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}((\ln(b))^{\alpha+1}-1)$. Now for the improper integral I get $\lim\limits_{b->\infty}(\int_e^b(\frac{\ln(x)^\alpha}{x}dx))=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}\cdot(\lim\limits_{b->\infty}\ln(b)^{\alpha+1}-1)$

And because $\lim\limits_{c->\infty}\ln(c)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{c->\infty} c^{\alpha+1} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\infty & \alpha\geq -1 \\
1 & \alpha=-1 \\
0 & \alpha<-1
\end{array}
\right.
$

So the limit only exists for $\alpha<-1$, is this right?

Comment: This is the right result

Comment: Why do you consider  in the end the lim of a power of $c $ instead that of $\ln c $?

Comment: because ln(c) is infinity anyway

Comment: Does: $$\int{\frac{(\ln x)^{\alpha}}{x}dx}=\frac{(\ln x)^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha+1}+C$$ help? (FYI: I used IBP)

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_e^\infty\frac{\ln^a(x)}{x}dx$$
$$u=\ln(x),\,dx=xdu$$
$$I=\int_1^\infty u^adu=\left[\frac{u^{a+1}}{a+1}\right]_1^\infty$$
and this is clearly divergent

Comment: Except if $\alpha < -1$, I think.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes that sounds right